# Absolute positioned elements stack in opposite order (not as expected)

Tags: css

```css
#child_1, #child_2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
}

#child_1 {
  background-color: green;
}

#child_2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="child_1">Green Child 1</div>
<div id="child_2">Blue Child 2</div>
```

**Child 1** is positioned BEFORE **Child 2** in the HTML. I therefore expect **Child 1** to be displayed above **Child 2**, not the opposite way. Can someone explain what's going on?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The child 2 is not positioned before child 1, first child 1 is positioned absolutely and the child 2 is there over the child 1 so the child 1 element is not visible (it is below child 2)

Comment: why you think *before* and *above* goes together? it's more logical to have *before* and *below* together. When, in real life, you place elements the last one will be on the top

Comment: Yes, in the same way like real life the last element goes above the first element like you keep one book on another book, the child2 goes above the child1

Comment: Re the edit, duplicate questions don't by default get deleted, but instead stick around as signposts exactly to allow others to locate the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Stacking without the z-index property

As you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/#:%7E:text=Without%20any%20z%2Dindex%20value,elements%20with%20default%20static%20positioning.), the order of absolutely positioned elements is determined as follows:

> Without any z-index value, elements stack in the order that they appear in the DOM (the lowest one down at the same hierarchy level appears on top)

In your case, the lowest element in the DOM is `#child_2`, that's why it appears on top.

#### Use [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) for manual positioning

With this property, you can define a manual order on elements. An element with a higher z-index will be displayed above another with lower z-index.

Here's your modified snippet:

```css
#child_1,
#child_2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
}

#child_1 {
  z-index: 1;
}

#child_2 {
  z-index: 0;
}

#child_1 {
  background-color: green;
}

#child_2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="child_1">Green Child 1</div>
<div id="child_2">Blue Child 2</div>
```

Comment: *The order of elements in the DOM doesn't have any impact here.* --> it does when no z-index is specified

Comment: You're right, I updated the answer accordingly.